# Google Sheets: aggregate and extrapolate irregular data over time

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-charts

1. **I have a list in which I *now-and-then* (no fixed interval) enter the available budget.**
2. **Most of all I want to extrapolate this to a future trend of the coming 10 years.** (no rocket science, more of an average through line of the last 4-5 samples, as you would have in stock market charts or so)

**Possible as an inbetween step I would like to aggregate this to one average number per quarter.** As in most quarters there is no data available, it should mean interpolation. (or interpolation for *all*: so regarding Jan/April/Juli/Oct 1st. If it is always interpolated between the nearest neighbours... fine with me.)

*I am familiar with the common aggregate functions, but I have no idea, what to use on such irregular entered data. I have seen some stuff on extrapolation, but that was monstly on sequences (not x⤇y).*

### [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11SFKZULDQ8Ij2LOpN56kmGmxb1czAVkfzIGvsN1NU1M/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

**Thank you for your help :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, see [Test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DgKtleoyFDBkrn75FE1hn9BbVjxSvKrC2hAOZOIfoQ8/edit#gid=0)

Formula in cell C2 (with results in columns C:D) aggregates your data by quarters returning last date of respective quarter and average amount for this quarter.

```
=QUERY(
{B2:B,
ARRAYFORMULA(eomonth(date(year(EOMONTH(A2:A,0)),(quotient(MONTH(A2:A)-1,3)+1)*3,1),0))},
"Select Col2, AVG(Col1)
 Where Col1 > 0
 Group by Col2
 Order by Col2 Asc
 Label AVG(Col1) ''",0)
```

Columns E:F contain both actual data and projection based on given data. Projection is simple linear trend as you mentioned.

In particular formula in E2 returns quarters both known and projected, where

```
filter(C2:C,C2:C<>"")
```

includes quarters from initial data

and

```
arrayformula(eomonth(MAX(C2:C),SEQUENCE(40,1,3,3)))
```

takes last quarter in initail data and expands it for 10 more years (40 quarters - you can change it if needed)

Formula in F2 returns amounts both known and projected, where

```
={filter(D2:D,D2:D<>"");
```

includes amounts from initial data

and

```
TREND(
filter(D2:D,D2:D<>""),
filter(C2:C,C2:C<>""),
arrayformula(eomonth(MAX(C2:C),SEQUENCE(40,1,3,3))
)
```

returns linear projection based on initial data and expanded quarters for 10 years.

Comment: Very impressive. Thank you!